# Is it possible to know when the iPhone will go to sleep?

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications, sleep

Is there any notification I can listen to that will alert me that the phone will go to sleep? I have implemented the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
              addObserver:self 
                 selector:@selector(resignActive:)
                     name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                   object:nil];
```

but it seems that it's not getting triggered when the phone goes to sleep after some time of inactivity (1 min in my settings). The reason I think it's not working is that I have a timer that perform an action every second and if a certain time has passed (bigger than one minute) it issues an audio alarm. In my resignActive I invalidate my timer and that works fine when I press the home button, but not when the phone goes to sleep. It still seems to be running in the background but "at a lower speed" as the times are much longer than normal (around 10 min instead of 2 min).

Any ideas what's happening when the phone goes to sleep? I have read these two posts but it doesn't really answer my question.

[What happens to an iPhone app when iPhone goes into stand-by mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411436/what-happens-to-an-iphone-app-when-iphone-goes-into-stand-by-mode)

[Iphone app is delayed for 10 -15 minutes when iphone is in sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396786/iphone-app-is-delayed-for-10-15-minutes-when-iphone-is-in-sleep-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implements those 2 methods on the UIApplicationDelegate :

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

It will be called also when a push notification from another app (or a SMS) is shown...

Comment: What a good start of the week.

Based on your concise and correct answer I changed my method above to subscribe to UIApplicationWillResignActive.

It now works as I want it to.

Thanks for a perfect answer. Wish they were all like this.

Comment: just happy to help... have a nice week