# Code execution on iOS, using background audio

Tags: ios, background-process

First of all, I have to say that I am **not** interested in publishing in the appstore, but at the same time I am **not** interested in jailbreaking my phone.

I want to experiment with code execution in the background, so I'd like to write a simple application that periodically logs my battery level and my position, let's say every 10 minutes. I don't want to schedule local notifications, so to my understanding, this would only be possible (?) going the '[Pastebot way](http://tapbots.com/blog/pastebot/pastebot-music-in-background)'.

Can someone please give me more information about that? If I want to test it, will I have to schedule a timer and properly configure my audio session? Or, in other words, I don't understand where my "background executing code" should be placed. Any help/information highly appreciated!

Comment: This has been answered at this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396786/iphone-app-is-delayed-for-10-15-minutes-when-iphone-is-in-sleep-mode][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396786/iphone-app-is-delayed-for-10-15-minutes-when-iphone-is-in-sleep-mode

Comment: @jakob very nice, I didn't manage to find that through search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use location services, than you can set your application background mode in app info.plist (**UIBackgroundModes** and add to it **location** item). And in your application start monitoring location change. Thats it, your application won't be suspended (till system will be in heavy position with memory for other process).

Comment: Thank you @moonlight, but I'm mostly interested in background execution when playing background audio.

Comment: And thats exactly what I told you in my comment. That flag allows work for applications which require GPS tracking even in when they in background.